# How to speed up streamlit app by delegating computation to a background process?

Tags: streamlit

I'm not sure about the wording of the question, but my problem is that I have some slow to compute and somewhat unimportant things to display in a streamlit app - and it'd be good to find a way to update the ui with these values without blocking the entire app while they are being calculated.

Consider this app:

```py
import streamlit as st

def slow_function(...):
   ...

def fast_function(...):
   ...

input_text = st.text_area('Paste your text here')
c1, c2 = st.columns(2)

with c1:
    st.metric('Important', fast_function(input_text))

with c2:
    st.metric('Less Important', slow_function(input_text))
```

The entire app basically freezes while the `slow_function` is running (note that caching would not help in this case).

I have an intuitive feeling that some form of "update this widget when you `slow_function` finishes, but don't block for it" would be nice, but not sure what the best way to achive this would be.

Comment: You may want to have a look here: [https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/streamlit-and-asynchronous-functions/30684](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/streamlit-and-asynchronous-functions/30684)